# Unity3d script seems to work in one scene but not another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a group of scenes for an opening menu (Start, Options, Exit, etc).

Right now, I have the exact same "Back" 3d Text GameObject in two of my scenes that have the same script that when clicked, uses Application.LoadLevel("Main") to return to the Main scene.

The problem is, "Back" only works in one of the scenes. It does not seem to be working in the other. They are identical (Script attached, position, name, etc.).

Any ideas what might be causing this or why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed the problem by copying over all of the assets in the problem scene to a new scene. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: Next time, you may find more help at [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). It is directed specifically at game design, and people there are in general more knowledgeable about game engines such as Unity3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by copying over all of the assets in the problem scene to a new scene. Now it works like a charm.